# SQL Server 2008 remote logins fail, local succeeds, remote logins enabled?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running SQL Server 2008, with remote connections enabled, and mixed Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication enabled. The logins I have setup (Windows and SA) work fine from the server. However, when I login from a remote computer, I receive the error "Login failed for user ...".

Any ideas? Before I was receiving a "remote connections not enabled" error, but enabled that and now receive this new error.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I was specifying port 2434 with my connection string. This is not necessary, and causes problems. Removing the port specification fixed this issue.

Comment: *chuckle*  Wish I had a nickel for every horked connection string I've written...

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem, in my case SQL Server Browser service was not running on my SQL server.  Starting that service removed the error and allowed me to connect remotely.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Check the SQL Server error logs to see if you can more detail on why the login is failing.
You should see some variation of a 18456 error.
This blog post is a great resource for troubleshooting those errors:
http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx

2)  If you don't see an 18456 error in the error log, then your attempt to connect is not reaching your SQL Server.  Check to see if there are any firewalls blocking the ports (either on your server, on your client, or in between).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SQL Server Browser service running then you have no need to specify the port number if not running on 1433.  FYI for future reference.